# Numpy Boolean Bitwise unexpected behavior

Tags: numpy, indexing, bitwise-and

I have a code which takes a numpy array of prices, and find discounts in desired range.
For some reason, the output is not as expected.

My code is:

```
# prices
prices = np.arange(5, (1-0.4-0.01)*5, -0.1)

# calculate discounts for each price
discounts_calculated =  (max(prices)-prices)/max(prices)

# choose prices in range of (10,30) percent discount
chosen_inds = (0.1<=discounts_calculated) & (discounts_calculated<=0.3) 
chosen_discounts = discounts_calculated[ chosen_inds ]

# show output
print(prices)
print(discounts_calculated)
print(chosen_discounts)
```

and the output is:

```
[5.  4.9 4.8 4.7 4.6 4.5 4.4 4.3 4.2 4.1 4.  3.9 3.8 3.7 3.6 3.5 3.4 3.3
 3.2 3.1 3. ]
[0.   0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1  0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.24 0.26
 0.28 0.3  0.32 0.34 0.36 0.38 0.4 ]
[0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.24 0.26 0.28 0.3 ]
```

Whereas the expected output should include the `.1` element at the last array:

```
[5.  4.9 4.8 4.7 4.6 4.5 4.4 4.3 4.2 4.1 4.  3.9 3.8 3.7 3.6 3.5 3.4 3.3
 3.2 3.1 3. ]
[0.   0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1  0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.24 0.26
 0.28 0.3  0.32 0.34 0.36 0.38 0.4 ]
[0.1 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.24 0.26 0.28 0.3 ]
```

How can I change the code so that the bitwise comparison would work?

Comment: @BigBen indeed changing to `prices = np.linspace(5, (1-0.4)*5, int(0.4*5/0.1)+1 )
` yield the desired output. Could you elaborate or refer to source which explain why is that?

Comment: Read the docs of `np.arange` and `np.linspace`.  Also look at the `prices` result before doing further calculation.